# Doing your own electrical work

Tags: electrical, wiring

In Florida, you're allowed to do your own electrical work. With that being said here is my question. A really good friend of mine bought a 12'x 30' shed for a workshop. He is doing the electrical work and he asked me if I would help him because I know a great deal more about electrical wiring than he does. So would it be legal for me to help him wire his shop even though I'm not licensed?

Comment: Have you considered googling for the actual rules on Florida? In my jurisdiction, not in Florida, yes a home owner can do electrical but they still need to obtain a “homeowner permit” from the electrical AHJ. And yes a friend can help where I live. However the rule is that you cannot PAY someone to help. The help must be freely given. Check with the AHJ in your town.

Comment: This isn't really about home improvement, more of a legal issue.

Comment: Pulling a permit is a separate question and not responsive to the OP's question.  In my area (western Washington state), it's OK to pay a person who isn't a licensed electrician to "pull rope"...slang for drilling holes and pulling cable. They can't make up any connections or work in a panel, but they can pull cable.   Also, I've helped many friends wire houses and remodels without being paid (isn't that what friends are for!?) bc I'm not licensed. I did it bc I didn't want them to screw it up! BTW, all the work I did passed inspection the first time...just bragging a bit!

Comment: Dang, just realized I didn't actually answer the OP's question, where I'm at, It's OK to help someone do electrical wiring if you're not licensed as long as you're not paid for it. I think @RibaldEddie pretty much said the same thing.

Comment: ppl, I'm not talking about the necessity of pulling a permit, that wasn't the OPs question. I dk why you are talking about that.  Even in my original comment, I said pulling a permit was a separate question. The OP asked if it was OK for him to help a friend UNPAID to wire a shed. The answer to that is YES, it's OK.  It's also OK for unlicensed paid people to drill holes and pull rope (cable). They can't do any connections or panel work, just drill holes and pull rope. My comment intentionally didn't address pulling a permit as those requirements vary widely by jurisdiction.

Comment: As George and Eddie stated most states a non licensed person can not be paid for electrical work, most require a contractor’s license on top of a E license, If a permit is required goes to the requirements of the jurisdiction, extending an existing may be allowed, normally adding a new branch circuit will require a permit or in my case a minor work sticker that I purchase from building codes this work is not normally inspected by an inspector but not many in my line of work is going to put 8 years of training and passing one of the toughest electrical exams on the line to save a few dollars.

Comment: Thanks y'all for the info. Like George said I'm just doing this because we're friends and I want to make sure he doesn't make any mistakes like box over fill violations and I'll show him how to calculate the load capacity of each circuit.